# how to use static folder in django for css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am new to django framework .I created simple welcome page now i want to include css file in my project.i cant apply css file in project .i got error like "NetworkError: 404 NOT 
FOUND - /static/css/hai.css"

[image: my project structure] 
this is my project structure

setting.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","templates"),
)
if DEBUG:
  MEDIA_URL='/media/'
  STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
  MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
  STATICFILE_DIRS=(
  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),
  )
```

url.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base.html

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and i tried to following links but i cant apply css  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t80DMAAps8

Comment: You're better off using the tutorial provided with the documentation to learn rather than using random youtube videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just a spelling mistake. You need to put one `S` after `STATICFILE` Thus it should look like:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),
  )
```

Hope this will do.

Answer (score 2):

Django collect static automatically in `STATIC_ROOT` accessed by `STATIC_URL`. Put your "base" statics like bootstrap in your project package (project package is a dir with **init**.py) `simpleform > static > bootstrap > copy here all tree dirs from bootstrap package: css, fonts, js`. And store your application statics in `signup > static > also create css, js dirs`.

So if `hai.css` is one of basic css that you will use in your `base.html` put it to `simpleform > static > css > hai.css`.

**settings.py**

This is how you should make available project statics:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'simpleform/static'),
)
```

And for applications statics:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Also you have set a directory where django should store collected statics and uploaded media (and urls for accessing them). For example this is set it to `src > static` and `src > media`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**simpleform.urls**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

**template**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="{% static 'css/hai.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a simple file like this

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
OUTER_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(OUTER_DIR, "static", "templates"),
)

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(OUTER_DIR, "static", "static-only")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(OUTER_DIR, "static", "media")

STATICFILE_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(OUTER_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Then, in your code use `{% static %}` template tag.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Test this out with

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

If you turn off `DEBUG` then you need to add

```
if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Not when it's on as you have it now.

The `templates` directory shouldn't be in the `static` folder though. In general the specific files needed for `templates` and `static` should be inside your Django project not separate.