# Trying to fix css paths in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I'm working locally on a django project with bootstrap . The structure screenshot is above:

I have the following in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    

<head>  

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />   

    <title>Landing Page - Start Bootstrap Theme</title> 

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />   

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "css/landing-page.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />    

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static "font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    

</head>
```

In my settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
```

When I open "http://onetwentyseven.0.0.1:8000/index/", I see the html but the bootstrap css styling is not present.  in dev tools I see:

[image]

How can I fix the CSS paths?

Comment: Those paths look fine to me, are you sure they need fixing? Seems more likely that you just don't have anything serving your assets.

Comment: ... that means take a look to project `urls.py`. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653721/how-to-use-static-folder-in-django-for-css-and-javascript/26654433#26654433 some recommendations

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a syntax error. If you move the css directory from static>app1>css to static>css. It should work just fine

Comment: But isn't that against best practices? I think I've read in multiple places that the best way is to have a static subfolder for each app

Comment: If you want subfolders i would do: static>css. then in css have you bootstrap.css and the directory 'app1' which contains 'landing-page.css' then in your template change     <link href="{% static "css/landing-page.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />    to     <link href="{% static "css/app1/landing-page.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: thanks Tim, I made the changes but it did not work. I found http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/03/serving-static-files-in-django/#servee which helps my understanding