# How to get django static files in app directory?

Tags: python, django

I have some doubts about accessing django's static files.

VERSION: 1.8.4
VARs in settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
            # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\', '/')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

1. setting STATICFILES_DIRS, and adding `django.template.context_processors.static` to context_processors in `TEMPLATES`, so I can use 'static' tag in template. A src tag like: `src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/example.js"` or `src="{% static 'js/example.js' %}"` will generate a url to `http://myhost/static/js/example.js`.
2. If I want load static files in app directory, what should I do? As my understanding of django-official-doc,
   `STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
   )`
   the finders will search `app/static` in default, but if a `src="static/js/example.js"` in `app/templates/index.html`, the server will return a 404 code. Until I add `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` to `app/urls.py`.

What i want to know is:

1. Why 404? When load static file form `app/static` without `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`.
2. If I want to get static file in `app/static`, how to write url in a flexible way? cause `{{STATIC_URL}}` or `{% static %}` both point to project/static.

I have spend hours in reading related post on stackoverflow. Any help would be sooo greatly appreciated.

Comment: look at `simpleform.urls` http://stackoverflow.com/a/26654433/3033586

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code in your projects `settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/public/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Then you should be able to access the contents in the url like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/static/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Let say you have project named `MyProject`
provided you must have a folder named

`Myproject->public->static->js->bootstrap.min.js`

inside your projects directory .

and in your webpages you can simply refer to it by :

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope the idea is very clear . In Case of doubts revert back.

Comment: location is not defined; if I get another app also with a static sub-directory, you sure this will work?

Comment: No need to put static directory in each of your Apps .Keep the static directory only in MyProject named directory . How to access i have already shared .Give a try then only you will appreciate .:)

Comment: I get clear on put all static file in PROJ_DIR/static. but if distribute static files into sub-dir in each app, how to do? just like wagtail, a django-based cms. I want to understand how it works, even if not  use in this way.

Comment: I don't understand Why u need to do that . When you could have all things kept at one place that too without a mess , as u could create sub-directories inside static, that too with the name you want , like your app names, . Anyways keep trying . If you find something please post here too, As i havn't came so far on any project with such requirement .

Comment: There are two ways how people manage static files and one such way is to have static directory per app plus the root one, where everything gets dumped whenever `manage.py collectstatic` is called. Having everything only at a single location all the time is not optimal if people are working on different apps that are part of the same project completely separately. Also, as mentioned, `location()` is undefined. Please update your answer to at least fix this issue. Where is this `location` coming from?